# Integrability of Rademacher Fourier series

Tags: probability, measure-theory, fourier-series, lp-spaces

I don't know where to start with this problem:

Let $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence that satisfies $\sum c_n^2<\infty$ and $r_n(t)$ be the Rademacher function (i.i.d. random +1, -1 signs).

Define:
$$f_t(x) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty r_n(t)c_n\cos(nx)
$$
Show that $f_t(x)\in L^p([0,2\pi])$ for almost all $t\in[0,1]$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean $L^2$ instead of $L^p$? If so this is an immediate consequence of a theorem of Hoffman - Jorgensen. Tp prove the convergence in $L^2$ it is enough to show that $max\{||r_n (t) c_n cos(nx)\}|| has finite second moment.

Comment: I suspect it may help to look up "Khinchine's Inequality"; apply that and Fubini to $ |f_t(x)|^p$ and see what happens...

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy ??? If $p=2$ there's nothing to be proved; it's obvious that $f_t\in L^2$ for _every_ $t$, just because $\sum_n|r_n(t)c_n|^2=\sum|c_n|^2<\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if the OP hasn't got it yet he's not trying. For everyone else: Khinchine says that $$\int_0^1|\sum r_n(t)\alpha_n|^p\le c_p\left(\sum|\alpha_n|^2\right)^{p/2}$$ for any $\alpha_n\in\mathbb C$. So Fubini, or more properly Tonelli, shows that $$\begin{aligned}\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}|f_t(x)|^p\,dxdt&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1}|f_t(x)|^p\,dtdx\\&\le c_p\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum|c_n\cos(nx)|^2\right)^{p/2}\,dx
\\&\le c_p\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum|c_n|^2\right)^{p/2}\,dx
\\&=2\pi c_p\left(\sum|c_n|^2\right)^{p/2}
\\&<\infty.\end{aligned}$$

Hence $\int_0^{2\pi}|f_t(x)|^p<\infty$ for almost every $t$.

**Curiously,** not really about Fourier series at all; orthogonality of those cosines has nothing to do with it, the same thing works with any uniformly bounded sequence of  functions in place of $\cos(nx)$.